# Is ECDSA breakable by quantum computers?

Tags: encryption, public-key-infrastructure

Is ECDSA secure from quantum computers? Will quantum computers be able to calculate it's private keys from the knowledge of the public key once there are working quantum computers?

Comment: You might get better answers to this question at the [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Short answer: [Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography#Quantum_computing_attacks).

> Elliptic curve cryptography is vulnerable to a modified Shor's algorithm for solving the discrete logarithm problem on elliptic curves.

Comment: "Yes" is a vague answer because the asker posed two opposite questions: "Is ECDSA breakable by" and "Is ECDSA secure from" quantum computers.

Answer (score 12):

To quote from [pqcrypto.org](http://pqcrypto.org/): "Imagine that it's fifteen years from now. Somebody announces that he's built a large quantum computer. RSA is dead. DSA is dead. Elliptic curves, hyperelliptic curves, class groups, whatever, dead, dead, dead." Worth a visit to their site to understand what crypto looks like after the (hypothetical) success of quantum computing.